# How to use FindFit to do kinetic simulation?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, simulation, chemistry

I'd like to simulate the chemical kinetic model by fitting the experimental data. Here are my codes for simulation.

```
data = {{0.`, 0.003207613963640383`}, {0.256348`, 
0.751307591324145`}, {0.5004879999999998`, 
0.946609520707414`}, {0.7568359999999998`, 
0.9997534786329835`}, {0.9887700000000001`, 
0.9788588889284163`}, {2.0019530000000003`, 
0.7107228417712506`}, {3.00293`, 0.4859859783085131`}, {4.003906`,
 0.329989302539268`}, {5.004883`, 
0.2236874613858439`}, {6.005858999999999`, 
0.15155994391149338`}, {7.006836`, 
0.10294001208237556`}, {8.007815`, 
0.07060326258953398`}, {9.008785`, 
0.048587435830738386`}, {10.009765`, 0.033384617610655296`}};

Clear[knn, kf, knf, a];
ttime = 10.253905;
knf = 0.4;
a = 2.36;
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
S1'[t] == (-kf*S1[t] - knn*S1[t]),
NN'[t] == (knn*S1[t] - knf*NN[t]),
S[t] == a*NN[t],
S1[0] == 1, NN[0] == 0}, S, {t, 0, ttime}, {kf, knn}]

fit = FindFit[data, model[kf, knn][t], {{kf, 1.5}, {knn, 2}}, t]
Plot[model[kf, knn][t] /. fit, {t, 0, ttime},Epilog -> {Red, Point[data]}]
```

I have tried the condition that kf = 1.5, knn = 2, a = 2.36 can roughly fit the data by using manually change the parameter. However, I get an error like this.

```
ParametricNDSolveValue:: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions
```

I don't know how to fix this problem. I hope if I take {kf, knn, a} these 3 parameters to freely fitting with suitable initial value, I can also correctly fit the data and the rate constants are physically reasonable.(0 < kf, knn < 10, a has no constrained )

I would appreciate any help in rebuilding the code.

Many Thanks!

Comment: If you remove `S[t] == a*NN[t]` and replace `,S,` with `,NN,`, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

A quick "fix" would be to remove `S` from the `ParametricNDSolveValue` command:

```
Clear[knn, kf, knf, a];
ttime = 10.253905;
knf = 0.4;
a = 2.36;
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{S1'[t] == (-kf*S1[t] - knn*S1[t]), 
  NN'[t] == (knn*S1[t] - knf*NN[t]), S1[0] == 1, NN[0] == 0}, 
  NN, {t, 0, ttime}, {kf, knn}];

fit = FindFit[data, model[kf, knn][t], {{kf, 1.5}, {knn, 2}}, t]
(* {kf -> -1.17998, knn -> 4.35971} *)

Plot[model[kf, knn][t] /. fit, {t, 0, ttime}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image: Model fit]

A better fix would be to directly use `S` instead of `NN`, incorporate the estimation of `a`, and use `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
a =.;
model2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{S1'[t] == (-kf*S1[t] - knn*S1[t]), 
    S'[t] == a (knn*S1[t] - knf S[t]/a), S1[0] == 1, S[0] == 0}, 
   S, {t, 0, ttime}, {a, kf, knn}];

fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, model2[a, kf, knn][t], {{a, 1}, {kf, -1.5}, {knn, 4.4}}, t];
fit2["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 1.0003133640741626, kf -> -1.1786150346863764, knn -> 4.3583459462046354} *)

Plot[model2[a, kf, knn][t] /. fit2["BestFitParameters"], {t, 0, 
  ttime}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image: Fit with updated model]

With `NonlinearModelFit` you can get measure of precision for the estimated parameters (standard errors, confidence limits, correlations among parameters, etc.) and an assortment of model checking features. 
 One essential feature is a look at the residuals (as you are assuming a particular error distribution):

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{fit2["PredictedResponse"], fit2["FitResiduals"]}],
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Predicted", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Fit vs residuals]

One can see a definite pattern remaining suggesting that more is going on that what the current model can describe.  Also there appears to be a single data point that needs checking out.

Comment: Thanks! These help me a lot!